# StackOverflowError when trying to establish connection to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am currently getting a very strange error when I try to establish a connection to my MySQL database by using the Java jdbc driver. The error is not really helping me to solve the issue. How can I fix this?

Please find the code and the error message below:

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
        
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3305/testDB", "root", "");
    }
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1430)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T13GcmWriteCipherGenerator$GcmWriteCipher.encrypt(SSLCipher.java:2019)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.t13Encrypt(OutputRecord.java:451)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.encrypt(OutputRecord.java:414)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.deliver(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:316)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1212)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketSender.send(SimplePacketSender.java:55)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketSender.send(TimeTrackingPacketSender.java:50)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.send(NativeProtocol.java:568)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:632)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings(NativeProtocol.java:2107)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.scanForAndThrowDataTruncation(NativeProtocol.java:1938)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readAllResults(NativeProtocol.java:1670)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings(NativeProtocol.java:2109)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.scanForAndThrowDataTruncation(NativeProtocol.java:1938)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readAllResults(NativeProtocol.java:1670)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings(NativeProtocol.java:2109)
       ...
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.scanForAndThrowDataTruncation(NativeProtocol.java:1938)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readAllResults(NativeProtocol.java:1670)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings(NativeProtocol.java:2109)
```

Additional remarks: mysql_connector is added to classpath, port 3305 is active

Comment: From TheGlovner: *"Do you know the version of the jdbc driver you are using, online searches seem to suggest there was a bug in 3.0.7 with an infinite loop. Which would lead to the stackoverflow.

http://www.websina.com/bugzero/faq/exception-mysql-overflow.html"*

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/69645225/833070)

Comment: I am actually using a higher version, but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation for Connector/J connection establishment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) suggests using this line.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Try that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but it is also not working ...